# Interface with multiple implementations in ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I've got an interface that has two different implementations.

```
public interface IProducer
{
}

public class Producer : IProducer
{
}

public class FaultProducer : IProducer
{
}
```

I have two different classes that both take an IProducer as a dependency.

```
public class ConsumerChannel
{
    public ConsumerChannel(IProducer producer)
    {
    }
}

public class TradePublisher
{
    public TradePublisher(IProducer producer)
    {
    }
}
```

`TradePublisher` needs a Producer and `ConsumerChannel` needs a `FaultProducer`.  I can only bind `IProducer` to one implementation.  In Windsor I could do this with named bindings and `Dependency.OnComponent` but I can't find similar abilities in Ninject.  Is there a way to inject specific dependencies in Ninject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [named bindings](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#simple-constrained-resolution-named-bindings) for Ninject:

```
Bind<IProducer>().To<FaultProducer>().Named("FaultProducer");

public TradePublisher([Named("FaultProducer")] IProducer producer)
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in my bindings?  i.e., is there a way to keep my binding information in my NinjectModule in the same way i can use WithConstructorArgument for other arguments?