# Ninject Multiple Type Constructor

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have started to use Ninject today because Structuremap let me down big time.

I hit an issue when I began registering the same types with the same interfaces but I have have named them (as shown below).

```cs
kernel.Bind<IDataContextAsync>().To<DbGeoContext>().InRequestScope().Named("DbGeoContext");
kernel.Bind<IDataContextAsync>().To<DbEspContext>().InRequestScope().Named("DbEspContext");

IParameter geoUnitOfWorkDbContext = new ConstructorArgument("dataContext", kernel.Get<IDataContextAsync>("DbGeoContext"));
IParameter espUnitOfWorkDbContext = new ConstructorArgument("dataContext", kernel.Get<IDataContextAsync>("DbEspContext"));

kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWorkAsync>().To<UnitOfWork>().Named("UnitOfWorkGeoContext").WithConstructorArgument(geoUnitOfWorkDbContext);
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWorkAsync>().To<UnitOfWork>().Named("UnitOfWorkEspContext").WithConstructorArgument(espUnitOfWorkDbContext);

**Fails here with: Error activating IDataContextAsync
```

More than one matching bindings are available.**

var t1 = kernel.Get("UnitOfWorkGeoContext");
    var t2 = kernel.Get("UnitOfWorkEspContext");

Could someone help me figure out what is going on here and how to fix it?

I understand at runtime Ninject wont be able to figure out which instance to inject, but I though this was what the 'Named' instances was for?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface with multiple implementations in ninject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119591/interface-with-multiple-implementations-in-ninject)

Comment: The constructor must have the `Named` attribute

Comment: Hi This is not a duplicate due to me trying to achieve all of the binding logic in the RegisterService method. I don't want to have to include the ninject library into my Repository layer.

Comment: The answer is still the same, since you are using `.Named("SomeUniqueString")` -- you must have the `Named` attribute in the constructor so that it knows how to resolve.

Comment: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#simple-constrained-resolution-named-bindings

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Please add your comment as the answer so I Can mark it. Thanks

Comment: Done -- posted, thanks!

Comment: If you could upvote too that would be appreciated

Comment: I havent got enough points buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Ninject to target multiple implementations of the same interface, you need to do so with the `.Named` call as you have done.  But you also need to add the `Named` attribute on the constructor so that Ninject know which implementation to resolve.

As shown here:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#simple-constrained-resolution-named-bindings

**Example**

```
class SomeClassThatConsumesOneOfYourImplementations
{
    public SomeClassThatConsumesOneOfYourImplementations(
        [Named("DbGeoContext")] IDataContextAsync context)
    {
        // Constructor logic...
    }
}
```